# jhipster react form onChange state Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, jhipster

I'm new to React and having some trouble with jsx when setting state in a form with two fields that does an ajax call to put a json object (response data) in the state's `field3`. I have the following:

```
export interface IMyClassState {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;

    field3: object;
}

export class MyClass extends React.Component<IMyClassProps, IMyClassState> {
    state: IMyClassState = {
        field1: '',
        field2: '',

        field3: null
    }

    ...

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </form>
        );
    }
};
```

In an example with only two fields I suppose I could just have different `onChange`s like so:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" onChange={this.onChangeField1}/>
...
```

but if I had 100 fields it'd be a problem, which is why I'm trying to get the state field's name directly from `e.target.name` in my `onChange`. This however, gives me the error:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMyClassState | Pick<IMyClassState, "field1" | "field2"
```

How do I get rid of this error? Is it possible to solve elegantly with a one liner like I've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is to fix the type of `e`. We can use a type query to tell typescript the type is the same as the `onChange` of `input`: `onChange: JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']['onChange']`

The second part is to fix the object literal which is inferred to be `{ [x: string]: string; }`. Ideally we could tell the compiler that `e.target.name` is a key of `IMyClassState`

```
onChange: JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']['onChange'] = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name as keyof IMyClassState]: e.target.value });
};
```

The above code does not work because typescript will still infer the type of the object literal to be `{ [x: string]: string; }`. The only way to get the compiler to infer the type we want is for `e.target.name` to be cast to a specific field of `IMyClassState`.

```
onChange: JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']['onChange'] = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name as "field1"]: e.target.value }); // Ok now
};
```

While it's not ideal to lie to the compiler this is the simplest option. Another option is to just cast the object literal.

```
onChange: JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']['onChange'] = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value } as any as IMyClassState);
};
```